# JavaScript Execute Ruby Script

Tags: javascript, ruby

Server/Client are the same box. Creating a UI to run ruby test scripts locally.

I want something like executing an ActiveXObject:

```
    w = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    w.run('test.rb');
```

File structure is as follows

```
>Project
  -index.HTML
  -custom.js
  >Scripts
   -Ruby Script
```

Comment: what exactly is your question? please be more specific.

Comment: `w.run('Scripts/test.rb');` ?

Comment: I want to execute a ruby script with a JavaScript function. ActiveXObject isn't able to execute a ruby file.

Comment: "Breaking on JScript runtime Error -(n"

Answer (score 3):

Assuming ruby is installed in the system and is included in the PATH variable. All you need to do is:

```
var w = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
w.run('ruby Scripts\\test.rb');
```

Comment: Making some progress here - although what happens now is a Ruby terminal is briefly opened and closed, but nothing else happens.